# "Cancer" rows that cannot be deleted in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```
mysql> select doc, term, item from relevanssi where doc = 26331;
+-------+------------------------+------+
| doc   | term                   | item |
+-------+------------------------+------+
| 26331 | yes                    |    0 |
| 26331 | zero                   |    0 |
| 26331 | ???                    |    0 |
| 26331 | ???                    |    0 |
| 26331 | ????                   |    0 |
+-------+------------------------+------+
```

I have no idea what those "???" are. They do not show up on query:

```
select doc, term, item from relevanssi where doc = 26331 and term = '???';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I really want to delete those "???" rows. How do I do that?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/characters-appear-as-question-marks-using-mysql-204051027.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem.  Here's what I did.

```
 select doc, term, HEX(term) hexterm, item from relevanssi where doc = 26331;
```

This will show you your messed-up column values in hexadecimal.

Then, when you know one you want deleted you can do this

```
 delete from relevanssi where  doc = 26331 AND HEX(term) = 'value from hexterm column'
```

(For what it's worth the Relevanssi plugin developer is quite responsive to inquiries from users.)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that there are some characters with a wrong encoding that ends in a `?`. You can delete them with a primary key (id). In your case it could be difficult because you don't have a unique primary key.

Perhaps you can create one column with an auto increment value and delete them with the generated id.